# How to update object that stored in memory from multiple tasks in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, task

I am storing object in memory via [Distributed Memory Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-8.0#distributed-memory-cache) and access it from different background services and controllers.

There are two services that reading the object from memory by its key id but need to update different properties (can be also class).

What is the better way to update the object? It could be that both services will try to update different properties but override property of other task.

Thanks

I tried before storing object read and lock with semaphore but it is not ideal solution because of performance

Comment: Have you considered an update process that works via a queue?

Comment: What does updating mean here? Exchanging the object in the cache with a new variant or changing the single instance via different references but still the same instance. For the first i don't see a way around some sort of locking mechanism. For the second there might be options if you can forecast that the updates will never hit the same property. If its just a "random" set of properties that might conflict your back to locking.

Comment: Update for example 
Object is a DeviceClass that have property Statuses( power,wifi...) and also have property of Data.
When updating the property of Status(power) other task can update property Status(wifi) and other task update Data.
After update the device object must be with all last updated information